# Springer Journal Class sn-jnl and cases environment

Tags: cases

I am using sn-jnl.cls provided by the Springer to submit a paper to a springer journal. However the cases environment gives rise to error

! Missing $ inserted.

$
l.8                   x^n, & \text{if } 2 | n;\

```
\documentclass[referee,pdflatex]{sn-jnl} 



\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
   (A^n) = \begin{cases}
                  x^n, & \text{if } 2 | n;\\
                  y^n, & \text{otherwise}.
                \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remember to load `amsmath` it might not be loaded automatically by the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\mid` for the vertical bar.

In math mode `\mid` makes a vertical bar with "thick `\;`" spaces on each side.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[referee,pdflatex]{sn-jnl} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        (A^n) = \begin{cases}
            x^n, & \text{if 2} \mid n;\\
            y^n, & \text{otherwise}.
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]

(`amsmath` is loaded by the class.)